# overline command in math mode with verbatim

Tags: verbatim, accents

Does anyone know how to get something like \overline{\verb!signal!} to work?  I cannot seem to figure out how to get \overline to understand a verbatim command.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Do you really need `\verb`?

Comment: Does `\overline{\mathtt{signal}}` work for you? What effect are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Unless you use trickery, verbatim cannot be used as arguments to other commands. Please give some background on what this is supposed to be used for.

Comment: Tried \mathtt and it didn't work.  I am trying to make the font within the \overline{ } to be using the verbatim font.  Perhaps, there's a better way of doing it, but right now it only works if you remove \verb!signal!

Comment: You can obviously do this:  \begin{eqnarray*} \verb!signal! = a \cdot b \end{eqnarray*}.  But, once you put in \verb within an \overline, it doesn't work.  For example, \begin{eqnarray*} \verb!signal! = a \cdot \overline{\verb!b!} \end{eqnarray*}.  Perhaps, I am just doing this so convoluted.

Comment: Here's my original declaration:  \begin{eqnarray*}
negate & = & \verb!op_type[2]! \cdot  \overline{\verb!op_type[1]!} \cdot \verb!\
op_type[0]! \end{eqnarray*}.  This doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks to everyone who is responding!  Sorry if I am not doing this correctly.

Comment: By the way, with `unicode-math`, you can `\setmathfont[range=tt]{Latin Modern Mono}`, or any other monospace font on your system.

Answer (score 1):

Not something I would do in my document, but here it is:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\textoverline}{\afterassignment\text@verline\let\next= }
\def\text@verline{%
  \setbox\z@=\hbox\bgroup\aftergroup\finishtext@verline
}
\def\finishtext@verline{$\overline{\box\z@}$}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\textoverline{\verb!abc{dd{\x!}

\end{document}
```

Don't use this in the argument to another command.

If you just need the typewriter font and no special characters, you can do it in a much simpler way:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\overlinett}[1]{%
  \ensuremath{\overline{\texttt{#1}}}%
}

\begin{document}

\overlinett{signal}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you!!!!!  That worked.  Interestingly, it didn't work if I had \overlinett{test_signal} unless I did \overlinett{test\_signal}, but since its a typewriter font, this makes sense with the \_.  Thanks again so much!!!!

Comment: @stineje if this answer solved your problem you could accept it as best answer, so other people can find it easily.

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{verbatimbox,amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{verbbox}signal\end{verbbox}
$\overline{\theverbbox}$
\end{document}
```

[image]